# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE when Inserting into table

Tags: php

I can't figure out why I have the syntax error I receive a syntax error on line 25 once i start adding values of $_SESSION part, I am new to php and coding so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Adjust error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include('includes/session_config.inc');
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); 

$q = "INSERT INTO cards (sender_last,
                         sender_first,
                         sender_email,
                         recipient_last,
                        recepient_first,
                         recepient_email,
                         subject,
                         message,
                         image,
                         identifier,
                         date_entered
                     ) 
        VALUES ($_SESSION['postcard']['from_first']',
                $_SESSION['postcard']['from_last']',
                $_SESSION['postcard']['from_email']',
                $_SESSION['postcard']['to_first']',
                $_SESSION['postcard']['to_last']',
                $_SESSION['postcard']['to_email'],
                $_SESSION['postcard']['subject'],
                $_SESSION['postcard']['message'],
                $_SESSION['postcard']['image'],
                $_SESSION['postcard']['identifier']
                NOW()
                )";
```

Comment: You have a `'` too much at the first line of `Values(...`

Comment: either loose the quotes inside the indices or wrap them with curly braces, why not bind them instead? you're using mysqli anyway

Comment: You have `'` s on the outside of your closing `]` s. Multiple infractions

Comment: You forget to add `,` comma before `NOW()` in your query.

Comment: its not good to user variable directly in query, save value in variable and see sql injection before using variable in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,  Don't use to long multidimentional array directly in query, Use like this save in varialbe then use it, and other also care full for SQL injection, and also u have missed the comma before **NOW()** at the end of query.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Adjust error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include('includes/session_config.inc');
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); 

$from_first     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['from_first']);
$from_last      =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['from_last']);
$from_email     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['from_email']);
$to_first       =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['to_first']);
$to_last        =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['to_last']);
$to_email       =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['to_email']);
$subject        =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['subject']);
$message        =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['message']);
$image          =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['image']);
$identifier     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['postcard']['identifier']);

$q = "INSERT INTO cards (sender_last,
                         sender_first,
                         sender_email,
                         recipient_last,
                        recepient_first,
                         recepient_email,
                         subject,
                         message,
                         image,
                         identifier,
                         date_entered
                     )
        VALUES ($from_first,
                $from_last,
                $from_email,
                $to_first,
                $to_last,
                $to_email,
                $subject,
                $message,
                $image,
                $identifier,
                NOW()
                )";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your values are strings, but you have only ending `'`: `VALUES ($_SESSION...', $_SESSION...'`, replace it with `VALUES ('{$_SESSION...}', '{$_SESSION...}'`. Also missing `,` before `NOW()` in values list